# Loading Images from documentDirectory to UICollectionView - Lag when scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode, scroll, swift3, uicollectionview

I am having issues where I have about 50 photos with various file extension (jpg/png..etc) and roughly 3mb per image, stored in documentsDirectory. When I try to load them to a collection view, the entire UI will lag when scrolling. I been on this problem for the last 2 days and have read many stackoverflow questions dealing with laggy collection view but I am still unable to resolve this. Any help is appreciated!

This is my code to configure my collectionView cell:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { [unowned self] in
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.cellImage.image = image
        }
    }
```

The confusing part is this code works just fine to display video thumbnails.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think your problem cause by the photos itself my suggestion is to use some image cashing API like [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) or [sd-image](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Comment: try to use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that though you load the `UIImage` from a background thread, the image isn't decompressed until the `UIImageView` attempts to draw it, which happens on the main thread.

You can add the following code on the background thread to decompress the image before you pass it to the main thread:

```
let context = UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
image.draw(at: .zero)
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: I have tried variations of this, but it seems to crash my app even faster... doesn't even give me any debug error. Memory overload perhaps ...